# How to hold an image in an enum in Java?

Tags: java, enums, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

As far as I understood you can put basically any kind of object inside an `enum`, this would include a `BufferedImage`.
This would mean that creating an `enum` as follows should work:

```
A(0 , ImageIO.read(new File("a.png")) , "foo" , true),
B(1 , ImageIO.read(new File("b.png")) , "" , true);
```

The problem is that you **have** to catch any exceptions with this way of creating a `BufferedImage`.

Now my question is:
Is is possible to place a `try/catch` **inside** the declaration of the `enum`, or should I just hold the file name and pass the actual `BufferedImage` when it's being requested?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your enum declaration already require a constructor in which you can catch and handle all exceptions.

```
public enum ImageEnum {

   A(0 , "a.png" , "foo" , true),
   B(1 , "b.png" , "" , true);

   private final BufferedImage image;

   private ImageEnum(.., String filename, ..) {
        // first assign to tempImage to meet teh final modifier of image
        BufferedImage tempImage = null;
        try {
             tempImage = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
        } catch (Exception e) {
             tempImage = null;
        }
        image = tempImage;
   }

}
```

Comment: Probably best to at least log the exception when you catch it.

Comment: With this I assume the enum would look something like this: `A(0 , "a.png" , "foo" , true)`

Comment: @yshavit: Yes, it's best to log the exception. But that's not part of the question and it depends on your logging framework.

Comment: @Uli: Do mind that with your current example you'll get a compiler error. In your catch image might already have been assigned, but it's a final, so you can't assign it again. I'd suggest adding a dummy variable for `image` to prevent this.

Comment: @uli it's not part of the question, but it's part of your answer so it's still relevant. Even a comment would be good -- just something to remind the op not to silently swallow the exception.

Answer (score 3):

What if you made a method that loaded the image and returned it, thereby catching any exceptions, and you could pass the path of the file. So your code could look like this:

```
A(0 , loadImage("a.png"), "foo" , true),
B(1 , loadImage("b.png"), "" , true);
```

This is just another option if you're like me and like to split things up into lots of methods.